# Graph API - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft Graph API.
I have given the relevant Graph API credentials for authentication.
It doesn't seem to connect and returns the following error:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /---(tenant-id)---/oauth2/v2.0/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016212518AC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))`

One thing to note is that this is in a corporate environment. Have set in the proxy to allow  connection to the address but still fails to connect. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported request, are you using below code to established a new connection?

import requests

page = requests.get('login.microsoftonline.com') ,

Comment: Yes, I had imported requests previously

Comment: Could you please share the code , will check where you are doing wrong ?